# Running Python script from PHP by using an AJAX call

Tags: php, python, ajax, cgi-bin

Hello I have a python script that I'm trying to run from PHP from the client side using an AJAX call like this :

```
$.ajax({
async: false,
cache:false, 
url:"callpython.php",
type: "POST",
data: "data1=" + path + "&data2=" + clr[k0], 
success: function (response) {
console.log(response);
}});
```

the code inside `callpython.php` is:

```
<?php
exec("python myscript.py",$return);
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

and the code inside `myscript.py` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import string
import cgi, cgitb
from lxml import etree
from PIL import Image

pet="images/rock1.png"
petColor="59A678"
.//The rest of the code that populates the variables printed down below
.
.
.
print "Content-type: text/html"
print 
print eyeSize
print displacementX
print displacementY
print distance
print textX
print textY 
print sizeText
print colorText
```

As Ajax result I get : `Array`

When I run the php code from console : `php callpython.php` it executes the python script and it gives me :                                                     `["Content-type: text\/html","","30","37","47","20","27","40","20","#91806F"]`
but when calling that same php file using ajax Firebug shows me : `[]` as result.

So please how can I get the same result in that Ajax call as the console results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, I would try outputting json from python.  What you are getting from python currently is a bunch of lines (a single string), not a valid json encodable list.  Also, you wouldn't need the Content-Type in the data as that is a header for use in HTTP.  Instead, try this:

**PYTHON**

```
import json
...
data_out = [eyeSize, displacementX, ...]
print json.dumps(data_out)
```

**PHP**

```
exec("python myscript.py",$return);
echo $return;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I did as you suggest me, now when running the php script from console I get :`["[\"30\", \"37\", \"47\", \"20\", \"27\", \"40\", \"20\", \"#91806F\"]"]`  and now the AJAX call gives me : `Array` instead of `[]` so the issue is still unsolved.

Comment: Hi I fix it, it was an error in my python code and I used `passthru()` function instead of `exec()`                         `header("Content-type: text/html");
echo passthru("python eyes/cgi-bin/eyes.py");`

Answer (score 0):

try to set header as below,

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but I get the same result as before : `[]`